# Cancel Subscription At Period End

Tags: php, stripe-payments

**QUESTION:**

How does one append the "at_period_end" argument to the following PHP function in accordance with the relevant Stripe documentation ?

**DOCUMENTATION:**

[STRIPE: cancel subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#cancel_subscription)

**CODE:**

```
<?php

require_once('./lib/Stripe.php');
Stripe::setApiKey("$APIKEY");

$cu = Stripe_Customer::retrieve("$CUSTOMER_ID");
$cu->subscriptions->retrieve("$SUBSCRIPTION_ID")->cancel();

?>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the correct solution to be:

```
$cu->subscriptions->retrieve("$SUBSCRIPTION_ID")->cancel(
     array("at_period_end" => true ));
```

Answer (score 7):

Try specify the argument as an array like this:

```
$at_period_end = true;
$cu->subscriptions->retrieve("$SUBSCRIPTION_ID")->cancel(
     array("at_period_end" => $at_period_end));
```